# A bc problem about long expression

Tags: shell, shell-script, bc, math

I want to calculate an expression in shell.
I use the following code:

```
pi=$(echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l)
i=3
d=`expr (1+c($pi*($i/10)+$pi))/2 | bc -l`
```

But it says

```
bad pattern: (1+c(3.1415926532*(3/10)+3.1415926532))/2
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `expr` in your last command
where you probably should be using `echo`.

P.S. I advise you to use the `$(…)` form in both `bc` commands (rather than `` `…` ``).

Comment: The expression also needs to be quoted to prevent the shell trying to parse the brackets

Answer (score 1):

If you take my advice you won't use `` or `$()` - it's a little silly. `bc` is an interactive, line-oriented interpreter. It reads in a line from stdin, checks if it needs another based on the input just read, and then either prints its results to stdout or prompts for more on stdin. Like your shell, it will even refuse to do anything more than line-buffer output even when it is written to other than a terminal. There is no need at all to call up a new `bc` for each calculation - especially in a command substitution which *also* involves calling a whole new shell and allocating a new pipe.

The best way is set up a co-process.

```
# in a bash shell
exec 8<> >( : ) 9< <( bc <&8 )
echo 'b=5;++b' >&8
read  b <&9
echo "$b"
```

---

```
6
```

And the `bc` will just keep running - all of those variable values that you're doing so much work to shuttle back and forth between ephemeral, command substituted `bc` processes could be more easily centrally stored in a central `bc`.

```
echo b\*b >&8; read b <&9; echo "$b"
```

---

```
32
```

And even better, since I learned how to do this the other day, you could put the `bc` process on a socket server.

```
{ ncat -l 9000 --allow localhost -k| bc; } <>/dev/fd/1 |:&
```

And with a shell that speaks the `/dev/tcp` language:

```
{ echo 'b=10;b' >&0; read b; echo "$b"; } <>/dev/tcp/localhost/9000
```

---

```
10
```

That can get a little cumbersome. I wrote a little function called *`bchat()`* to make it easier.

```
bchat(){
        local IFS=\;                                 ### separate on ;
        printf ${1+'%s;"\n"\n';}"$*"                 ### print \0 if no args
        set --                                       ### init  args
        while  read   bchat       &&                 ### while read <bc
              "${bchat:+set}" -- "$@" "${bchat:=$*}" ### append to args
        do :;  done 2>/dev/null                      ### and done
}       <>"$BC" >&0                                  ### $BC must be set
```

After setting up a socket server as demonstrated above, you might use that function like:

```
BC=/dev/tcp/localhost/9000
bchat b=5 x='(b--)' '"x="' ++x '"b="' --b
echo "$bchat"
```

---

```
x=6;b=3
```

...and again, that state will persist as long as the bc process does...

Answer (score 1):

Beware that where you set the scale has an influence on the calculation.

This script:

```
bc -l << \EOF
scale = 10
pi = 4 * a(1)
i = 3
(1 + c(pi * (i / 10) + pi)) / 2
EOF

bc -l << \EOF
pi = 4 * a(1)
i = 3
scale = 10
(1 + c(pi * (i / 10) + pi)) / 2
EOF

bc -l << \EOF
pi = 4 * a(1)
i = 3
r = (1 + c(pi * (i / 10) + pi)) / 2
scale = 10
r/1
EOF

bc -l << \EOF
scale = 100
pi = 4 * a(1)
i = 3
r = (1 + c(pi * (i / 10) + pi)) / 2
scale = 15
r/1
EOF
```

outputs:

```
.2061073736
.2061073739
.2061073738
.206107373853763
```